# FilterOperators or FilterOperatorType - The correct naming format for an enum in C#

Tags: c#, enums, naming-conventions

Which is the appropriate (more readable) way of naming enumerator? will you consider:

```
enum FilterOperators
{
    IsEqual, 
    Contains, 
    StartsWith
}

class QueryFilter
{
    FilterOperators Operator{get;set;}
}

var filter = new QueryFilter();
filter.Operator = FilterOperators.IsEqual;
```

Or is this preferable

```
enum FilterOperatorType
{
    IsEqual, 
    Contains, 
    StartsWith
}

class QueryFilter
{
    FilterOperators Operator{get;set;}
}

var filter = new QueryFilter();
filter.Operator = FilterOperatorType.IsEqual;
```

Also, *Colors* or *ColorType*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IrritatedVowel.com](http://www.irritatedvowel.com/Programming/Standards.aspx) suggests the following:

> **Enumerations**
>
> **Standard Based Upon Microsoft .NET Library Standards**
>
> Follow class naming conventions. Do
>   not add "`Enum`" to the end of the
>   enumeration name. If the enumeration
>   represents a set of bitwise flags, end
>   the name with a plural.
>
> **Why:** This convention is consistent
>   with the .NET Framework and is easy to
>   read.
>
> **Example:**
>
> `SearchOptions` (bitwise flags)
>
> `AcceptRejectRule` (normal enum)

As such, I believe the preferred choice would be `FilterOperator`.

Comment: As to your final suggestion, it seems that in common practice you might have a class 'FilterOperator' which is of one of the specified types, thus to name your enum 'FilterOperator' within the class, would be confusing. .NET itself doesn't do this, but rather uses the plural of the type. Ie. FontFamily.FontFamilies

Comment: I agree, Type is almost as redundant as adding Enum.  I would use FilterOperator and Color (C# uses Color not ColorType)

Comment: @SwDevMan81, pretty sure .NET uses 'Color.Colors' for the enum, at least in 3.5.

Comment: @DeusAduro Its just System.Drawing.Color.Chartreuse (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color_properties.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The "Framework Design Guideline" says:

> - Do use a singular type unless its a bit field
> - Do use plural types for flags enums (bit fields)
> - Do not use enum suffix
> - Do not use flag or flags suffixes
> - Do not use a prefix (e.g. ADO...)

So my suggestion would be `FilterOperator`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's all about agreeing on a standard (you can define your own) and then sticking to it. I'd say appending "Type" seems like a good idea, even though for something as simple as "Color" it might seem a bit silly. It does hint that it is an enum, which I think is nice.

I'd say go for the last example :)

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely subjective, but the first thing that pops to mind is 'Colors' strikes me as a list of many colors and seems appropriate. However, for a smaller list, like 'FilterOperatorType', the '...Type' seems appropriate.

In short, if their are many the plural of the word seems appropriate, if they are few and represent broad categories the '...Type' seems appropriate.